# Help understanding Binary Representation for Integers?

Tags: binary

I'm trying to understand these illustrations but there are parts which I don't understand:

- "But the computer had to count backwards for the negative numbers"

  - Why does adding a 1 to the front of a binary mean the computer has to count backwards?
- "Flip the bits and add 1!"

  - What does that mean add 1?

woops: http://csillustrated.berkeley.edu/PDFs/integer-representations.pdf

Comment: search for: wiki 2's complement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be easiest to show by example.  Here are the numbers from -4 to 4 represented in binary:

```
4   0000 0100
3   0000 0011
2   0000 0010
1   0000 0001
0   0000 0000
-1  1111 1111
-2  1111 1110
-3  1111 1101
-4  1111 1100
```

So say we want to go from 1 to -1.  We first flip all the bits of 1

```
1 0000 0001
  flip bits
-----------
  1111 1110
```

Then we add a 1:

```
  1111 1110
  +       1
-----------
  1111 1111
```

We now have -1.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing the illustrations, but you're probably talking about Two's complement representation. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)

1. Why does adding a 1 to the front mean the computer has to count backwards?

   Due to how carrying works, `FFFFFFFFF + 1 == 0`
   and `0 - 1 == FFFFFFFF`. All the bits get flipped, including the first bit. 
   If you simply define the negative numbers as those starting with a 1 bit (80000000 - FFFFFFFF) then you get a nice uniform behavior for addition with a natural overflow.
2. Flip the bits and add 1: in 2's complement, this negates a number

   `~x+1 == -x; // always true`

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is called [signed integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations).